# rsync - How to sync specifc files and delete the rest on destination

Tags: rsync

I want to sync specific files and delete anything else that exists on the destination server.

Source = /dir1/A - Z

How do I sync A - D and delete E - Z if they exist?

Answer (score 3):

[`--delete-excluded`](http://rsync.samba.org/ftp/rsync/rsync.html) pretty much does exactly what you're looking for:

```
rsync --exclude 'E' --delete --delete-excluded dir1/ remote:dir1/
```